# Why these subspaces are H-invariant?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

> **21.1.1 Theorem** (Clifford). A normal subgroup $H$ of a completely reducible group $G$ of linear transformations of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$, is itself completely reducible.

> Proof. Let $U_1$ be an irreducible $H$-invariant subspace of $V$. There exists a set $\{g_1,\ldots,g_s\}$ of elements of $G$ minimal relative to the property that the smallest $G$-invariant subspace $\hat{U}_1$ containing $U_1$ (in other words the closure of $U_1$ under $G$) is generated by the subspaces $U_i=U_1g_i$, $i=1,\ldots,s$. It follows from the normality of $H$ that the $U_i$ are $H$-invariant, and thence by

As on the screen, I don't understand why subspaces U_i are H-invariant.

Comment: The normality of $H$ implies that for all $h \in H$, we have $g_ih =h'g_i$ for some $h' \in H$, and it follows from that.

Comment: Please don't use images; many screen readers can't handle them, and they may not display property in all interfaces.